# Google Auto Factory / Dagger Integration: Dependencies on injected code

Tags: java, android, guice, dagger

It seems that Dagger doesn't explain at all how to deal with providing / managing auto generated code, such as what Google Auto Factory creates. Also the people at Google Auto don't really explain how to integrate back with Dagger so it's causing a pain for people like myself without very senior knowledge of how both libraries work.

The problem I'm seeing is that when you are not providing fully qualified names to factories generated by Google Auto Factory, Dagger will not pick them up at all. However, providing a fully qualified factory name will allow Dagger to link everything together correctly.

My question is that is this is this more of a general / undocumented issue while using Dagger you can come across or a bug that should be fixed in either library?

Works:

```
@Module(
        library = true,
        complete = false
    )
public class FactoryModule {

    @Provides
    MembersAdapterFactory provideMembersAdapterFactory(
        me.magneto.groups.adapters.MembersAdapterFactoryImpl membersAdapterFactory) {
        return membersAdapterFactory;
    }

}
```

Fails:

```
import me.magneto.groups.adapters.MembersAdapterFactoryImpl;

@Module(
          library = true,
          complete = false
       )
public class FactoryModule {

    @Provides
    MembersAdapterFactory provideMembersAdapterFactory(
        MembersAdapterFactoryImpl membersAdapterFactory) {
        return membersAdapterFactory;
    } 
}
```

Factory of:

```
public interface MembersAdapterFactory {

    public MembersAdapter make(
                       Context context, int resource, List<Member> members);

}



@AutoFactory(
    className = "MembersAdapterFactoryImpl",
    implementing = { MembersAdapterFactory.class }
)
public class MembersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Member> {


    private MembersAdapterHelper mMembersAdapterHelper;


    MembersAdapter(@Provided MembersAdapterHelper membersAdapterHelper,
                   Context context,
                   int resource,
                   List<Member> members) {
        super(context, resource, members);
        mMembersAdapterHelper = membersAdapterHelper;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just ran into this myself. Seems like a dagger bug.

Comment: I opened an issue over here: https://github.com/square/dagger/issues/456