# Square Dagger error: class is exclusively members injected / cannot be scoped required

Tags: android, dependency-injection, module, dagger

I get following error message from Dagger when compiling the module:

```
test.MyClass is exclusively members injected and therefore cannot be scoped required by test.MyModule for test.MyModule
```

Google is no help in this case.

I have a quite simple architecture: 1 module, all injected classes are listed in *injects* clause. I don't see anything what may cause a problem.

Comment: Just stumbled upon this one as well...

Comment: In my case I could get rid of it by removing a "@Singleton" from "test.Myclass".

Comment: And in my case I remembered that I had to specify - for whatever reasons - a injectable (empty) constructor. The little things... :)

Comment: Totally got hosed by this - thanks to @ThomasKeller for the tip.  I forgot about that dagger requirement for a minute.

Answer (score 0):

There error seems to be caused by not having an `@Inject` constructor.

In my case, I was using lombok constructor generation on the class. IE.

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__({@Inject}))
public class MyClass {
    private final AnotherClass anotherClass;
}
```

And changing to an explicit constructor resolved the problem.

I expect the failure is related to dagger running before the generated code is generated. (Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100115/google-auto-factory-dagger-integration-dependencies-on-injected-code) and the [related issue](https://github.com/square/dagger/issues/456).)